TypeOrm "leftJoinAndMapMany" with subquery
I have 2 tables - Subscriptions and Periods. I'm trying to join first and last periods in my Subsctiption. Here's a part of code of how I'm adding a subquery.
export class SubscriptionQueryBuilder {

 private readonly qb: SelectQueryBuilder<SubscriptionSchema>;

 constructor(
    private readonly repository: Repository<SubscriptionSchema>,
  ) {
    this.qb = this.repository.createQueryBuilder('sub');
    ...
    this.addPeriodsQuery();
 }

 ...

 private addPeriodsQuery() {
    const subquery = `
    SELECT "period"."id" AS periods_id, 
           "period"."subscription_id" AS periods_subscription_id,
           "period"."start" AS periods_start,
           "period"."end" AS periods_end,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY "period"."subscription_id" ORDER BY "period"."start" DESC) AS "start_rank",
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY "period"."subscription_id" ORDER BY "period"."end" ASC) AS "end_rank"
    FROM "subscription_period" "period"
  `;

    this.qb
      .leftJoinAndMapMany(
        'sub.periods',
        `(${subquery})`,
        'periods',
        'sub.id = periods.periods_subscription_id',
      )
      .andWhere('periods.start_rank = 1 OR periods.end_rank = 1');
  }

The generated SQL query seems to be right, but typeorms mapper just not maps data to the property.
@Entity()
export class SubscriptionSchema {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid', {})
  id: string;
  ...

  public periods?: SubscriptionPeriodSchema[];
  ... 

Does anybody succeed in working with leftJoinAndMapMany or leftJoinAndMapOne with subqueries?

Finally, I've finished with a solution based on getRawAndEntities. For some reason, I've missed that method. It is not ideal, but the repository pattern lets you manually finish mapping.
